# Mortgatge payment loop

Tags: r

I have to write a loop for the following mortgage payment:

```
balance 500000
APR 4.75
30 year loan
```

they want to make 1750 each month, the description says to keep looping until loan is paid off

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly

```
int = 4.75/100
monthly_payment = 1750
balance = 500000
for (i in 1:360)
{ intm = (1 + i) ^ (1/12)
balance = (intm*balance) - monthly_payment
if(!i %% balance) {
  next
}
print(i)
}
```

I tried the above loop and got 35, not sure if right.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I find this calculator very handy if you want to overpay your loan and lower the total interest paid during the course of the term. https://www.themoneycalculator.com/loans/calculators/loan-overpayment-calculator/#!/dealfinder/loans/

Comment: That payment doesn't cover the interest so the loan balance will not go down.  An interest only payment would be $1937 if the interest was calculated monthly as you are doing it.

Comment: usually payments are done monthly but interest is calculated as APR * (payment day - last payment day) / 365 over the balance at start of the period. Then you calculate the new balance after the payment as balance + interest - repayment. In your example the loan will only increase as the interest on monthly basis (assume january or any 31 day month as first period) which would be 1952.1 on interest, so if you pay only 1750 your dept keeps increasing